# Shared memory deleted at exit

Tags: shared-memory, python-3.8

I have two scripts, one that creates and writes a shared memory block, and the second one that reads that shared memory.
The problem is that when the first script ends, the shared memory is deleted even I do not unlink it.
Here's my first script :

```
import argparse
import csv
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time

from classes.rtData import RtData
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

if '__main__' == __name__:
    sys.stdout.write('starting server ... \n')
    service = RtData()

    shm_a = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='rtdata', create=True, size=len(msg))
    data = shm_a.buf
    data[0] = 42
    shm_a.close
```

When adding a breakpoint I can see that the shared memory is created :

$ ls -l /dev/shm/

total 0
-rw------- 1 facundo facundo 4 Sep 28 09:41 rtdata

But when the scripts exits, the shared memory is deleted ( so I can not read it with the second script )

Comment: The shared memory block will persist as long as any process has it opened. Terminating the creating process does *not* automatically delete the shared memory.

Comment: That's why my question.  Maybe the sequence should be : a) Process I creates the shared memory, but not closes it.  b) Process II opens the same shared memory and consumed it.  But that is not what I need.  The idea is one process has the responsabilty of keeping the shared memory updated ( but finish executing after doing that ) ... and then any other process that should be triggered access the shared  memory in order to consume it.

Comment: If I understand your scenario correctly it sounds like regular files would be a more appropriate solution. Shared memory (and similar concepts) are really for sharing data between *concurrently running processes*.

Comment: What I'm looking for is to handle a memory area shared by many processes that do not run at the same  time ( the wil run on request ).  It is toward data adquisition in a scada system.  What confuses me is the text in the docs "The shared memory block will persist as long as any process has it opened. Terminating the creating process does not automatically delete the shared memory" ( calling the .unlink method )

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason.
[The documentation states that](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory)

> When one process no longer needs access to a shared memory block that **might still be needed by other processes**, the `close()` method should be called

I've found this bug report related to this issue https://bugs.python.org/issue39959#msg368770

I've tested it in my process by adding `unregister( shared_memory_name, 'shared_memory')` in the consuming process, it works fine.

Comment: “Otherwise, `unlink()` is automatically executed” — Where do you see this? It’s at best implied, and, I’d argue, not even that. Furthermore, [based on the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py) this simply doesn’t seem to be the case. `__del__` calls `close`, but not `unlink`.

Comment: You're right.  I did not see that on the code. I will do further testing.  Thanks.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: It's a fairly over-engineered solution where, when the first named resource with OS-wide effect is created, a resource tracker process is created. The tracker process lives as long as there is a living writer for the pipe that communicates with it (meaning it usually lives as long as the parent process and all its children continue to live), then cleans up any resource registered with it that were not subsequently unregistered (e.g. because `unlink` was called manually, which in turn `unregister`s). Further details in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73159334/364696).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening, why, and how, and why the solution you found "works".

Shared memory can, on some operating systems, persist indefinitely if not explicitly unlinked, even if no running process is using it. This is a nasty resource leak that doesn't get cleaned up until the machine is rebooted. In C, that's on the programmer; if you didn't want it leaked, you should have been more careful. In Python, this violates general expectations (even if the programmer fails to do proper cleanup, Python will do it for you, emitting a `ResourceWarning` to the few developers who enable all warnings), so they didn't want to leave a potential leak scenario like this in there.

The solution to it is (on POSIX systems) a resource tracker process (from the undocumented `multiprocessing.resource_tracker` module) that is used automatically for any interprocess shared resources (right now, just shared memory and named semaphores). The resource tracker process launches separately, with a pipe opened from and written to in the parent, passed to the tracker, which the parent process (and its other children) write to when they want to register a resource for eventual cleanup.

The tracker process intentionally outlives the parent, constantly reading lines written from the parent process to register/unregister resources for cleanup. When all other processes holding the write pipe have closed though, its loop naturally terminates, and any remaining objects registered for cleanup are cleaned automatically, then the resource tracker itself exits.

What this means is:

1. If you don't unlink the shared memory yourself, the resource tracker will shortly after you, and all your child processes (that did not intentionally close the pipe to the resource tracker), have exited.
2. If you want to prevent this, as you found, you can manually communicate with the resource tracker to unregister the shared memory by running `from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import unregister`, then, after creating the shared memory, running `unregister(shared_memory_name, 'shared_memory')` to immediately tell the resource tracker "Never mind, I'll handle cleaning it up manually." (just make sure you actually do this)
3. This is needed even for more normal shared memory use cases (where process A launches first and creates/opens the shared memory, unrelated process B launches and opens it, process A exits, then process C launches and wants to open the same shared memory, which likely fails, as the memory was already unlinked, and only exists in an unnamed state until process B closes it's remaining handle(s) to it). [The bug you found](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84140) and [the still open duplicate it was closed in favor of](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/82300) is proposing documented solutions, but right now, no such solution exists, so depending on undocumented internals is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you are missing a manager process

for example (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiprocessing-python-set-2/):
import multiprocessing

```
def print_records(records): 
    """ 
    function to print record(tuples) in records(list) 
    """
    for record in records: 
        print("Name: {0}\nScore: {1}\n".format(record[0], record[1])) 

def insert_record(record, records): 
    """ 
    function to add a new record to records(list) 
    """
    records.append(record) 
    print("New record added!\n") 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager: 
        # creating a list in server process memory 
        records = manager.list([('Sam', 10), ('Adam', 9), ('Kevin',9)]) 
        # new record to be inserted in records 
        new_record = ('Jeff', 8) 

        # creating new processes 
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=insert_record, args=(new_record, records)) 
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=print_records, args=(records,)) 

        # running process p1 to insert new record 
        p1.start() 
        p1.join() 

        # running process p2 to print records 
        p2.start() 
        p2.join()
```

Comment: This seems orthogonal to OP’s problem — a manager isn’t necessary to use shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

According to the other comments, this is a bug in Python 3.8 (and still present in Python 3.10).

I tried to follow [user1077915's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64210571/1669975) but couldn't.
Reading more, I've found [turicas' solution](https://bugs.python.org/msg388287) and, besides this fix works only in Linux, it's fine to me.

The whole code with example is here: https://bugs.python.org/file49859/mprt_monkeypatch.py

As far as I understand, this code is kind of hacking Python's multiprocessing library, so an update to Python's version may eventually break the code.

For convenience, below is the full code, with an example. I tested it with success with Python 3.8.10 and Python 3.10.7 in Ubuntu for Windows.
I'm just sharing the code here. All credits go to the author.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, resource_tracker
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory


def remove_shm_from_resource_tracker():
    """Monkey-patch multiprocessing.resource_tracker so SharedMemory won't be tracked

    More details at: https://bugs.python.org/issue38119
    """

    def fix_register(name, rtype):
        if rtype == "shared_memory":
            return
        return resource_tracker._resource_tracker.register(self, name, rtype)
    resource_tracker.register = fix_register

    def fix_unregister(name, rtype):
        if rtype == "shared_memory":
            return
        return resource_tracker._resource_tracker.unregister(self, name, rtype)
    resource_tracker.unregister = fix_unregister

    if "shared_memory" in resource_tracker._CLEANUP_FUNCS:
        del resource_tracker._CLEANUP_FUNCS["shared_memory"]


def create_shm():
    remove_shm_from_resource_tracker()

    print("create_shm started")
    shared_mem = SharedMemory(create=True, size=1024, name="python_testshm")
    shared_mem.buf.obj.write(b"X" * 1024)
    shared_mem.close()
    print("create_shm finished")

def destroy_shm():
    remove_shm_from_resource_tracker()

    print("destroy_shm started")
    shared_mem = SharedMemory(create=False, name="python_testshm")
    result = shared_mem.buf.tobytes()
    shared_mem.close()
    shared_mem.unlink()
    print("destroy_shm finished")

def main():
    p1 = Process(target=create_shm)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    p2 = Process(target=destroy_shm)
    p2.start()
    p2.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```